# Spring Boot asking for a Service @Bean in the configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've been working for the past year with Java microservices in Spring Boot, but I've never worked with APIs directly. So I've decided to create my own API that I will implement in a Service, meaning in a different project.

So I guess maybe here is where I am going wrong. I can't create the API without the implementation. Am I forced to implement the API in this project (I don't think this is the answer)

As you can read on the title, I am having issues with my Service Interface and the Bean's in the configuration class.

The error I am getting is the following

---

Field alumnService in com.project.shareitAPI.api.controller.AlumnController required a bean of type 'com.project.shareitAPI.api.service.AlumnService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.shareitAPI.api.service.AlumnService' in your configuration.

---

I have a Service Interface like this

```
@Service
public interface AlumnService {

    AlumnDTO postNewAlumn(AlumnDTO body);

}
```

A Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/alumns")
@Slf4j
public class AlumnController {

    @Autowired
    AlumnService alumnService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/new")
    public ResponseEntity<AlumnDTO> postNewAlumn(
            @RequestBody AlumnDTO body
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(alumnService.postNewAlumn(body));
    }
}
```

And here is the configuration class with the @Bean that is requesting but I know this ain't right.

```
@Configuration
public class ShareItConfiguration {

    @Bean
    AlumnService alumnService(){
        return new AlumnService() {
            @Override
            public AlumnDTO postNewAlumn(AlumnDTO body) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Maybe I am not understanding the concepts of how an API works or is structured, but how should it be then? Because I don't understand the error.

Thanks for the help and knowledge!

### Edit

Here is the project structure just if you need to know

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG8ng.png)

### Edit2

Log of all the Beans at startup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTyIz.png)

Comment: But actually, by providing this `@Bean` you implement it ... Please remove `@Service` from interface, (i guess) this causes the error/confusion.

Comment: Add a breakpoint (or System.out) at `return new AlumnService()` line to check if it is actually called on application startup. And as said above remove `@Service` from interface.

Comment: Correct me please if am wrong but that AlumnService @Bean in the configuration shouldn't be there? Honestly, I don't understand what it's actually doing. I took the@Service and it works as long as the Bean of the service is defined in the config file.

Comment: @ILyaCyclone I've added a log in the main class that logs all the Beans and it shows the AlumnService bean, I will add a screenshot of it.